How to combine static OpenAPI content with dynamic content from annotations?
We are using Quarkus 3.12.3 with io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi to generate OpenAPI document at both build time and runtime, we also use the swagger-ui properties to include the Swagger UI with our application.
We need to augment/combine some static OpenAPI content in a file with the above generated OpenAPI document.  The docs say to place the static content in META-INF/openapi.yaml or to specify the custom location via additional-docs-directory,  However neither of those approaches work, the static content is never combined with the generated OpenAPI results.
How can I enable the combining of content?
We placed the static content at the location specified in the documentation.  We were expecting it to work per the documentation.

What you did should work. (see https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#loading-openapi-schema-from-static-files). So are you saying that doing this does not generate the combined schema if you go to http://localhost:8080/q/openapi ?
